# Is it possible to use Android Studio's decompiler from command line?

Tags: android, android-studio, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I'm a begginner in android pentest and I'm using some decompiler like jadx but sometimes It does'nt work on decompiling some classes,

but when I drag and drop the .class file in android studio it decompiles it.

So is there a tool that use the android decompiler to decompile android application ?
Or is there any way to decompile a complete APK without drag & droping each class files to android studio ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here: `$(Android Studio)/plugins/java-decompiler/lib/java-decompiler.jar`

Running from command line:

```sh
$ java -jar java-decompiler.jar org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler
```

Sources: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine

You can decompile whole `*.jar` at once if you wish.